# Where should I request a new feature on EL&U?

Tags: feature-request

Being new here (well, I joined EL&U over a year already, but hadn't been very active, until recently), I don't know where I can suggest some improvement to EL&U. Please advice.

I just discover the "Favorites" features, which is a nice way to bookmark questions I think might be useful in the future. However, I think it would be much better if I can mark **any specific answer** in any question as one of my favorites (as opposed to bookmarking the entire question). So I don't have to wade through all the answers in the question, trying to recall which one was really the reason that made me bookmarked it in the first place.

Where can I submit such a request?

Comment: Silly me. It's only logical many people would want and must have been requested before. Just can't find it in meta EL&U made me think my request is a brand new one. Thanks a lot, both of you. :^)

Comment: You may post an answer in *your own* browser's list of bookmarks: copy the link address from the 'share' link beneath the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either here on Meta, or, since this is a change that would affect all sites of the network, the [meta Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Be aware, however, that this particular request has been submitted before, several times in fact, and right now it doesn't look like it's going anywhere:

- 1 July 2009 — [Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer) ("just bookmark the link in the browser")
- 9 July 2009 — [Mark Answer as Favorite/Star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star) ([status-declined](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined))
- 31 January 2012 — [How do I save or bookmark some best answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120802/how-do-i-save-or-bookmark-some-best-answers) (closed as dupe)

See also [Can we re-request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your feature request has already been [proposed and denied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star).

As you can see, the link goes to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), that site handles things that affect the whole Stack Exchange network.

You can also post such requests here and tag them as [feature-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

If the feature request is something that will affect the architecture of the site, it will probably be best posted on MSO because the SE devs will have to deal with it.